# 'Remit' an antonym of itself?

Tags: meaning, verbs, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

Perhaps I don't fully understand the word, but it always confuses me.

When talking about money:

> The money was remitted.

Which means that the money was transmitted/transferred successfully.

But it also means:

- Cancel or refrain from exacting or inflicting (a debt or punishment).
- Pardon (a sin).

What are the reasons that when referring to money as remitted, it is a positive, otherwise negative?

Comment: Simple. It's an exchange situation, so obligations and transfer work in both directions. Like _credit_ (Lat 'he trusts') and _debit_ ('he owes'), _remit_ (< _remittere_ 'send back, relax, diminish, abandon') has to do with keeping, collecting, or cancelling obligations to pay. If you _remit your payment_, your debt is remitted. Works both ways, like _transfer_.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the noun generally associated with remitting money is _remittance_, while the related noun generally associated with pardon (for example, of sin) or abatement (for example of an illness) is _remission_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of remit as meaning "to let it go".

So in case of monetary payments, it ends up meaning transfer.

In case of monetary receipts, it is renouncement.

In case of duty, it is dereliction.

In case of punishment, it is forgiveness.